# Searching SQLite database according to user input

Tags: android, sqlite, search, recipe

I'm creating an Android app that will search for recipes according to ingredients that the user chooses. For the life of me I can't figure out the query necessary for this.

I have a Recipe and an Ingredient table, as well as a RecipeIngredient junction table which has RecipeId and IngredientId columns that serves as a connection between recipes and the required ingredients.

For example, let's say the user chooses 3 ingredients and clicks search, what is the required query in order to display the recipes that use those 3 ingredients?

I've been trying to figure it out, but I don't have the slightest idea of what I need to do.

Comment: Post something if you have tried first

Comment: I have tried, but I to be honest I don't know what the hell I'm doing. What I've been trying so far is yielding completely different results than I expect. This is really frustrating...

Comment: Lol I don't understand why I always get thumbs down on my questions...

Comment: Because people are not finding it useful please read how to ask good questions so that people upvote your questions.http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This you would do if you search is based on name of the ingredient that user types in (you can also use LIKE):

```
SELECT * FROM ingredient WHERE name='name_of_ingredient'
```

//Note: if the user selects ingredient that is an object of class Ingredient, then you dont need this query, as you can get the IDs of them straight away, assuming that you have a field id in your Ingredient class.

Then you extract ids of those three ingredients that the user chose and put them in the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM RecipeIngredient WHERE ingredientid=x OR id=y OR id=z
```

You get all the recipe IDs where any of those ingredients appear. Although ,you only want those which have all of them in them, so just go through your recipes and count the appearance of every ID. And print out only those that happen to be 3x in the result.

There of course is a more efficient way, this is just to show you a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "like" keyword in your query -

for example -

```
 select * from Ingredients where ingredient like 
'%ingredient1%' or ingredient like '%ingredient2%'
```

The above query will show the data(recipe) where any of the ingredients would be getting used. If you want to show the data that contains each of the ingredient, you can use 'and' in place of 'or'.

Also, I would suggest you to make the ingredients separated in your table with any separator like comma,pipe,semicolon etc. so that you can differentiate between more than two ingredients for same recipe.

Example - if you save "||ingredient1 ||ingredient2 ||ingredient3" in your table,

(I have used 2 consecutive pipes as separator to differentiate between two ingredients so that you can filter your search accordingly)

Then, your query would be like -

```
select * from Ingredients where ingredient like 
    '%||ingredient1%' or ingredient like '%||ingredient2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT recipes_names FROM Recipe WHERE id = (SELECT RecipeId FROM RecipeIngredient  WHERE IngredientId = (SELECT id FROM Ingredient WHERE ingredients_name LIKE <%ingridient_1%, %ingridient_2%, %ingridient_3%>))

so recipes_names and ingredients_name - columns in Recipe and Ingredient accordingly.

But we need more details for complete answer

Comment: It's telling me there's a syntax error near "<"... I tried something else, but it's only showing me one recipe when I type an ingredient that's also relevant for other recipes. This is what I tried: SELECT RecipeTitle FROM Recipe
WHERE RecipeId = (SELECT RecipeId FROM RecipeIngredient
WHERE IngredientId = (SELECT IngredientId FROM Ingredient
WHERE IngredientName = "olive oil"))

Comment: Provided request is nothing but template until I do not know the exact column's name of your DB, you cannot use it as it is.

Correct me if I wrong:

Recipe has RecipeTitle and RecipeId columns

RecipeIngredient has RecipeId and IngredientId columns

Ingredient has IngredientId and IngredientName  columns